# How to put data outside of pie in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I am learning D3.js and came up with the following plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/VYH5QbO99ZbMkvc2D4Fe?p=preview

All I need is a way, so that the text can sit outside of pie (arc). For Example like ....

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053424/label-outside-arc-pie-chart-d3-js)?

Comment: I tried that, but my text is not fitting, I am doing something wrong here