# Adding a legend to a D3.js pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js pie chart
[image]

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var piecolors = d3.scale.category20c();

var w = 600,
    h = 460,
    r = (Math.min(w, h) - 50) / 2;


var dataFile = ".\\temp\\" + "<%=justOutFile.toString() %>";
d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {

    var svgPie = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(r)
        .innerRadius(2);

    var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(r-100)
        .innerRadius(r-5);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.Distinct_Count; });

    var pie = svgPie.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    pie.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
          .attr("data-legend", function(d){return d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP})
      .style("fill", function(d) { return piecolors(d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP); });

    pie.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        var midAngle = d.endAngle < Math.PI ? d.startAngle/2 + d.endAngle/2 : d.startAngle/2  + d.endAngle/2 + Math.PI ;
        return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d)[0] + "," + labelArc.centroid(d)[1] + ") rotate(-90) rotate(" + (midAngle * 180/Math.PI) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr('text-anchor','middle')
          .style("font-size", "12px")
          .style("font-weight", "900")
          .style("font", "sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.Distinct_Count + " " + d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP  + " " + d.data.PERCENTAGE + "%"; });

legend = svgPie.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50,30)")
            .style("font-size", "12px")
            .call(d3.legend)
});

</script>

<style>
.legend rect {
 fill:white;
 stroke:black;
 opacity:0.8; }


body {
  font: 10px 'Open sans', sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.2px;
}

div#chart {width: 100%;}

</style>

<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

What I am trying to do is, add in a legend to either side of my pie chart
all the examples I tried so far, I didn't understand. Can someone please help me create a legend. I am not sure if I have built the pie chart using best practices, if that is the case, please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675617/how-to-add-legend-to-a-pie-chart-using-d3js-and-how-to-centralise-the-pie-chart

Comment: yes I saw that one but i seem to have a problem with the part assigning legend = svg.append("g")  not sure uf what that relates to in my code I tried svgPie.append("g") and svgPie.append("pie") I get the error

Comment: Unable to get property 'setProperty' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 doesn't come with a method called `legend`. Therefore your line `.call(d3.legend)` will fail.

However, you can build `d3.legend` yourself. [Here's an example from GitHub user ZJONSSON](https://gist.github.com/ZJONSSON/3918369#file-d3-legend-js). Don't forget to credit him, if you use his code.

In case you have no luck with his code, you can easily do it yourself:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend-entry').data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend-entry')

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'legend-rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function (d, i) { return i * 20 })
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr('fill', function (d) {
    return piecolors(d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP)
   })

legend.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'legend-text')
  .attr('x', 25)
  .attr('y', function (d, i) { return i * 20 })
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP
  })
```

Add some styling, and you have a pretty decent legend. If you add some click handlers on each element, you can also implement a filter function.

Comment: yes I see that now it is added no luck however I am having trouble figuring out how the legend = part works what i should be wiring up to in my code

Comment: Do you follow his [instructions](https://gist.github.com/ZJONSSON/3918369#file-readme-md) and add a `data-legend` attribute to your segments?

Comment: @j.doezer In case you have no luck to make his code work, I've added some example code to build a simple legend. It's basically a rectangle combined with a text element.

Comment: pie.append("path")
   .attr("d", arc)
          .attr("data-legend", function(d){return d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP})
   .style("fill", function(d) { return piecolors(d.data.BUSINESS_UNIT_GROUP); });

Comment: Aaaagghhh I am an idot the legend=svgPie.append("g")n is correct the acctual problem was i had d3.legend.js but had forgotten to paste the code in to it :( now it is working thanks all

Comment: Always the little things.