# D3 pie (donut) chart label outside of each arc

Tags: d3.js, label, donut-chart

I am new to D3 and I've got my donut chart however I can't get arc labels outside of each arc.

I want to get something like labels in purple in http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2295263, but I can't get it working for my donut chart.

I am using following code to append each arc's label but it seems like arc.centroid not working as expected.

```
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    arcs.append("svg:text")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        d.outerRadius = svgOuterRadius + 40; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = svgOuterRadius + 35; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle") //center the text on it's origin
      .style("fill", "Purple")
      .style("font", "bold 14px Arial")
      .text(function(d, i) { return 'label'+i; }); //get the label from our original
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wemEE/1/) is my JSfiddle:

I really appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your arc `path` segments are translated and you don't take that translation into account when adding the labels. If you look at the example you've linked to, you'll see that the `path` segments are added without any translation, which means that the `text` elements can be added without an additional offset.

To fix simply take the offset into account:

```
arcs.append("svg:text")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
          var c = arc.centroid(d);
        return "translate(" + (svgWidth/2 + c[0]) + "," + (svgHeight/2 + c[1]) + ")";
})
// etc
```

Full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wemEE/2/).

Comment: Thank you so much, It looks great. Can I ask you one more thing? I wanted the each label to be outside of each arc however adding d.outerRadius = <my outer radius> + 50; d.innerRadius = <my outer radius> + 45; before arc.centroid(d) did not help. Do you know how I can get each label position outside of each arc?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053424/label-outside-arc-pie-chart-d3-js) should help.