# How can I adjust the labels on a DC.js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have a DC.js pie chart with some really small values comparatively. I'm trying to adjust the labels so they aren't on the actual chart. I want them to be off preferably with lines drawn to the slices. (something like this http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/media/htmlchart-piechart-simple-example.png)

I'm can't find any examples of this with DC.js and the only thing close is this ([Label outside arc (Pie chart) d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053424/label-outside-arc-pie-chart-d3-js)), with d3.js, but I'm a little confused as how to implement in dc.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think currently you would have to suppress the built in titles with `.renderTitle(false)` and then implement the custom titles in a [renderlet](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#renderletrenderletfunction). You would reselect the slices and then apply pretty much the code in that other question. The data will already be attached to the slices.

The titles would appear a moment later, as that's how renderlets work, but perhaps that wouldn't be such a bad effect.

Of course, I haven't tried this, just a suggestion..