# D3pie.js labels.inner distance from the center

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use http://d3pie.org/#docs-settings
But there is no such parameter as the distance from the center to the internal labels.
Can someone tried to do it?
I want to move the internal labels closer to the outer edge of the circle.
Thank you so much.

now so:

[image]

need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can position the labels by defining a new arc as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270668/2314737 and then applying the `centroid` function.

I defined a new arc `newarc` with an inner radius equal to 2/3 of the outer radius.

```
var newarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(2 * radius / 3)
    .outerRadius(radius);
```

Here's the JS code:

```
var width = 300;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var dataset = [11, 13, 18, 25, 31];

var radius = width / 2;
var innerRadius = 0;
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie();

var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + ", " + radius + ")");

//Draw arc paths
var color = d3.scale.category10();

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    console.log(d);
    return color(i);
})
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("d", arc);


var newarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(2 * radius / 3)
    .outerRadius(radius);

// Place labels
arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + newarc.centroid(d) + ")";
})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.value + "%";
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/kvz8uev8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to enroll in another way.
I added my property in the object and function of positioning inner labels in D3pie file d3pie.js

This function is located on the line - 996 d3pie.js

```js
positionLabelGroups: function(pie, section) {
  d3.selectAll("." + pie.cssPrefix + "labelGroup-" + section)
   .style("opacity", 0)
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var x, y;
    if (section === "outer") {
     x = pie.outerLabelGroupData[i].x;
     y = pie.outerLabelGroupData[i].y;
    } else {
     var pieCenterCopy = extend(true, {}, pie.pieCenter);

     // now recompute the "center" based on the current _innerRadius
     if (pie.innerRadius > 0) {
      var angle = segments.getSegmentAngle(i, pie.options.data.content, pie.totalSize, { midpoint: true });
      var newCoords = math.translate(pie.pieCenter.x, pie.pieCenter.y, pie.innerRadius, angle);
      pieCenterCopy.x = newCoords.x;
      pieCenterCopy.y = newCoords.y;
      
      //console.log('i ='+i , 'angle='+angle, 'pieCenterCopy.x='+pieCenterCopy.x, 'pieCenterCopy.y='+pieCenterCopy.y);
     }

     var dims = helpers.getDimensions(pie.cssPrefix + "labelGroup" + i + "-inner");
     var xOffset = dims.w / 2;
     var yOffset = dims.h / 4; // confusing! Why 4? should be 2, but it doesn't look right
     
     // ADD VARAIBLE HERE !!! =)
     var divisor = pie.options.labels.inner.pieDistanceOfEnd;
     x = pieCenterCopy.x + (pie.lineCoordGroups[i][0].x - pieCenterCopy.x) / divisor;
     y = pieCenterCopy.y + (pie.lineCoordGroups[i][0].y - pieCenterCopy.y) / divisor;

     x = x - xOffset;
     y = y + yOffset;
    }

    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
   });
 },
```

I add var divisor = pie.options.labels.inner.pieDistanceOfEnd;

Then I spotted this property devoltnyh the configuration file bhp and passed for plotting parameters.

```js
inner: {
   format: "percentage",
   hideWhenLessThanPercentage: null,
   pieDistanceOfEnd : 1.8
  },
```

Meaning pieDistanceOfEnd: 1 hang tag on the outer radius of the chart
value pieDistanceOfEnd: 1.25 turn them slightly inward ....
You can play these parameters and to achieve the desired option.

Answer (score 0):

In d3pie.js look for the function *positionLabelGroups*. In this function both labels (outer and inner) are positioned.

To modify the distance from the center you can play with the x,y here:

```
x = pieCenterCopy.x + (pie.lineCoordGroups[i][0].x - pieCenterCopy.x) / 1.8;
y = pieCenterCopy.y + (pie.lineCoordGroups[i][0].y - pieCenterCopy.y) / 1.8;
```

What I did was decreasing the 1.8 to 1.2 and obtained what youre looking for. Dont know what the other vars do, but you can study the code to figure it out