# Label outside arc (Pie chart) c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, c3.js

I want to show the label data outside the graph area using c3.js. I've not find any help from documentation. Please some one guide me to solve this.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
      columns: data,
      type : 'pie'
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        label: {
            text: 'data1 ',
            position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      },
      y: {
        label: {
            text: 'data2 ',
            position: 'outer-middle'
        }

      }
    },
    pie: {
      label: {
        show: true
      }
    },  
    onrendered: function() {

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may helps https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1982

Comment: with d3 : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8053424/3256489